# Store input box value and use as default value

Tags: vbscript

I found this code - on this site I believe. It's doing the first part of what I need by storing an input box value to a text file. The next part I'm trying to do is have that same text file value populate the input box when I re-open the vbs file - so in effect the last value entered in the input box becomes the default value of the input box.

```
Dim objFSO 'File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objTS 'Text Stream Object
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\TextFile.txt", ForWriting, True)
objTS.Write(InputBox("Here it is"))
objTS.Close()
```

Comment: You use the same commands to read the file.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap your Const to read and call the `ReadLine` method then pass that to your `InputBox`

```
Dim objFSO 'File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objTS 'Text Stream Object
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\TextFile.txt", ForReading)
strContent = objTS.ReadLine
InputBox(strContent)
objTS.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Alex! The text is added as a title of the input box and I was looking to have it in the text area of the input box

Comment: -[Like this ](https://ittimepass.files.wordpress.com/2016/12/inputbox-default-edit.png?w=616)

Comment: Sorry, gotta get used to commenting :-)

Comment: I did that - InputBox("Message","Title",strContent) but get error cannot use parentheses when calling a sub

Comment: Got it - Call InputBox("Message","Title",strContent)